# Rails 3 Polymorphic Associations Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I've been trying to switch my `Orders` model to a polymorphic association with my `Product` and `Service` models. However, I have a few questions that I haven't been able to find answers to, even after watching the RailsCast and reading the documentation (so, those suggestions are appreciated, but I need a more concrete answer).

Question:

1. Is a polymorphic association the best thing to use in this case? Prior to this, I was using a `Transaction` model that had multiple `belongs_to` associations and used a custom Parent function to determine which one it was. This was working fine, but someone suggested a polymorphic association may clean things up.
2. I set up the polymorphic association properly and have been unable to have the `transactable_id` and `transactable_type` automatically populated. The code is below. I have side-stepped this by manually putting them in inside the form, but if anyone knows the proper way to do it, that would be great!
3. How can I access elements with polymorphic associations? For example, in my Cart object (which `has_many` Transactions and which `Transactions` `belongs_to`) I can no longer access things using `@cart.transactions.each do |t| ... @t.product.name` type coding.

My model associations look like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :orderable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :as => :orderable
end
```

My forms used to look like this:

```
<% form_for [@orderable, @order] do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And were rendered like this in my `Product` Show view:

```
<%= render 'orders/form' %>
```

Now, I pass a variable for the product.id in the render partial and use it to populate the `transactable_id` field. But, I feel like that is very messy.

Again, I have read the tutorials and API docs and have been unable to solve this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. If your business login implies that multiple models will have related model with the same fields so you should use polymorphic association. (In your case you can use it).
2. If set up polymorphic association Rails will automatically handle setting `*_id` and `*_type` fields depending on associated parent model.
3. Lets say you have Product with many orders in polymorphic association and you want to define which model order belongs to:

   ```
   order = Order.first
   order.orderable
   ```

Comment: One follow-on question: Is Rails supposed to automatically handle the `*_id` and `*_type` fields without any modification to the controller? Or, do you have to make the `build` changes to the controller?

Comment: yes it is, Rails will automatically set this fields when you create new polymorphic record

Comment: For some reason, it's not populating those fields automatically for me with the `Order` controller unmodified. The fields are in the model and the appropriate relationships are setup. Is there something wrong with the form that I setup above? Should the variables be passed in an array like that? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think there is no problem in form - it's just passing parameters to action. Maybe you have some wrong logic in action?

Comment: Ok, I'll double-check the controller actions. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, remember  - your polimorphic assoc. has the same interface as has_many or has_one. Creation is just(for example): Product.first.orders.create(...)